# publish Android app with new name and images

Tags: android, android-studio

I already have an app on android store and want to publish another.
The new one should have different name and images but all the back end is same.
Along with version number what are the things that I have to change to avoid any conflict? Do I have to change package names and all such stuff. Can some one please mention the things I have to change for publishing the new app.

Comment: You're probably looking for flavours, google for that and you will see

Comment: Awesome, Cheers mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The final package that is used in your built .apk's manifest, and is
>   the package your app is known as on your device and in the Google Play
>   store, is the "application id".
>
> The package that is used in your
>   source code to refer to your R class, and to resolve any relative
>   activity/service registrations, continues to be called the "package".

You should read about **[Configure Build Variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html)**

**Do I have to change package names and all such stuff.**

A product flavor defines a customized version of the application build by the project. A single project can have different flavors which change the generated application.

```
    android {  
    productFlavors {
        devel {
            applicationId "Your Id"
        }

        prod {
            applicationId "Your Id 2"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main identifier for Google Play is application package name. So you should change package name of your app. All other (version code, version name, images etc.) is relevant but is not necessary to be changed.